# For Nested Loop Asterisk Triangle

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested

My professor shared this code in class and I don't really understand it. Can anyone explain to me what exactly is happening in this program?

```
#Task 1: Prompt the user to input the number of rows of the triangle.

rows = eval(input("How many rows should the equilateral triangle have?"))

#Task 2: Calculate how many asterisks in the last row, write outer loop.

for i in range(rows + 1):

#Task 3: For each outer loop, calculate how many spaces and asterisks need to be printed in each row.

    emptySpaces = rows - i

#Task 4: Write inner loop to print spaces and asterisks.

    print(' ' * emptySpaces + '* ' * i)
```

and this is what the output looks like

```
How many rows should the equilateral triangle have?6

     * 
    * * 
   * * * 
  * * * * 
 * * * * * 
* * * * * *
```

Comment: What part don't you understand? Do you understand the link between the code and the comments?

Comment: Did your professor really share something with `eval()` (where `int()` would've been fine) as some kind of answer key?

Comment: Also, if your professor shared something in class, the proper course of action is to ___raise your hand and ask___. That's what the class is for.

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables - it helps to understand code. You can split your print to few steps to see what's going on in this line. ie. `print(''>', ' ' * emptySpaces, "<")`, `print(">", '* ' * i, "<")`, `print(">", ' ' * emptySpaces + '* ' * i, "<")`. `>` and `<` let you see spaces in text.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the program goes:

**Start:**

- The program starts and the user is asked for input.
- The User enters the Input (x) and the eval function converts the input to int, if the input entered is an integer.

**The loop:**

- The Loop starts from i = 0 and goes on till i = x.
- In the first iteration of the loop when i = 0, the following happens: The variable empty space is set equal to x, and the print statement prints x empty spaces and zero '* 's.
- In the second iteration when i = 1, empty space is set equal to x-1,and the print statement prints x-1 empty spaces and one '* '.
- In the third iteration when i = 2, empty space is set equal to x-2,and the print statement prints x-2 empty spaces and two '* 's (which is equal to '* * ').
- This goes on until i = x.
- In the last iteration when i = x, empty space is set equal to x-x which is zero, and the print statement prints 0 empty spaces and x '* 's.

The Loop is executed x+1 times and the program outputs x+1 lines. The first being empty and the last having x '* 's.

And that's all.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I needed :)